# Insert a row in a table with referencing to a value from other table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, **subject** and **student** respectively

```
 id |            name
----+-----------------------------
  1 | Math

id | student_name | score | subject_id
----+--------------+-------+------------
 11 | Mark         |  78.5 |          2
```

I have the Java code

```
public boolean insertStudent(String student_name,float score,String name) {
        boolean res=false;
        try(PreparedStatement statement=this.c.prepareStatement(INSERT_STU);){
            statement.setString(1,student_name);
            statement.setFloat(2,score);
            statement.setString(3,name);
            res=statement.execute();
            
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I have the query string for INSERT_STU

```
private static final String INSERT_STU="INSERT INTO student(student_name,score,subject_id) VALUES(?,?,(SELECT id from subject where name=?))";
```

This works in postgres. But is there any other way to do it?
*It has to be passed with subject name (String name) and not subject id. Since I won't be knowing the subject_id, I pass the name.

Comment: By the way… So a student can be assigned to only a single subject & score? I suspect your data model is not correct. You likely have a Many-to-Many relationship which requires a third bridging table.

Comment: If you know the subject id, why not just do a plain insert? What’s your question exactly?

Comment: @BasilBourque For now, I am just learning this where a student has a single subject. I am just wondering if there's any other way I could write the INSERT query with inner join?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your query to this which probably is more readable :

```
INSERT INTO student (student_name,score,subject_id) 
SELECT ?,?,id from subject where name = ?
```

but be careful here , if we can't find any match in subject table for given name , nothing will be inserted.